# vb.net getting an array to work in a sub

Tags: arrays, vb.net

So i got some array which i want to populate with data from a data table. I got a sub that should populate the array but I get the error, Redim statement requires an array. here is my code:

this is how I declared my array in my public class

```
Public TstukkenArray(1, 0) As String
```

this is my code which should populate the array with the data (this is where I get the error):

```
    'data from dataset to array
Sub LoadDataToArray(ds As DataSet, tablename As String, Array As Array)

    'counters 
    Dim i As Integer = 0
    Dim c As Integer = 0

    Dim arraywidth As Integer = ds.Tables(tablename).Columns.Count
    Dim arraylength As Integer = ds.Tables(tablename).Rows.Count

    'set array size
    ReDim Array(arraywidth, arraylength)

    'loop through table rows
    Do While i < ds.Tables(tablename).Rows.Count

        '
        c = 0
        'loop through columns and write data
        Do While c < ds.Tables(tablename).Columns.Count

            Array(c, i) = ds.Tables(tablename).Rows(i).Item(c)

           c = c + 1
        Loop
        i = i + 1
    Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: Firstly, there's no such thing as calling an array. Only methods get called.

Comment: As for the issue, that third parameter should not be type `Array` but rather `String(,)`. The documentation for `ReDim` (which you should have read before posting here) even says: "Note that if you declare a variable to be of type Array, the ReDim statement doesn't have sufficient type information to create the new array".

Comment: Also, just like when you create an array in the first place, `ReDim` requires upper bound values, not lengths.  As such, you should be using `arraywidth - 1` and `arraylength - 1`. I'd strongly recommend `For` loops rather that `Do` loops as well.

Comment: Also try not to use type names for variables, i.e. `Array`. I am not sure if this is what breaks your code, but it certainly does not help the readability.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To recap comments by @jmcilhinney and @Noceo

```
Public TstukkenArray(1, 0) As String
    'data from dataset to array
    'not be type Array but rather String(,)
    'try not to use type names for variables, i.e. Array
    ' if you declare a variable to be of type Array, 
    'the ReDim statement doesn't have sufficient type information to create the new array
    Sub LoadDataToArray(ds As DataSet, tablename As String, strArray(,) As String)
        'ReDim requires upper bound values, not lengths. 
        'you should be using arraywidth - 1 and arraylength - 1
        Dim arraywidth As Integer = ds.Tables(tablename).Columns.Count - 1
        Dim arraylength As Integer = ds.Tables(tablename).Rows.Count - 1
        'set array size
        ReDim strArray(arraywidth, arraylength)
        'loop through table rows
        'strongly recommend For loops rather that Do loops as well.
        For i = 0 To arraylength
            'loop through columns and write data
            For c = 0 To arraywidth
                strArray(c, i) = ds.Tables(tablename).Rows(i).Item(c).ToString
            Next
        Next
End Sub
```